# Retrieve widget from TableItem

Tags: java, swt, jface

I built a Table (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table) and used a TableEditor to add 2 checkboxes on each TableItem (row).

```
TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(tableClientes, SWT.NONE);
TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(tableClientes);

Button checkEnviar = new Button(tableClientes, SWT.CHECK);
checkEnviar.pack();

editor.minimumWidth = checkEnviar.getSize().x + 5;
editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
editor.setEditor(checkEnviar, tableItem, 0);

editor = new TableEditor(tableClientes);

Button checkMarcar = new Button(tableClientes, SWT.CHECK);
checkMarcar.pack();

editor.minimumWidth = checkMarcar.getSize().x;
editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
editor.setEditor(checkMarcar, tableItem, 1);
```

Now I need to read the state of each checkbox on each row, but I can't figure out how.

I tried retrieving the TableItem this way:

```
tableClientes.getItem(x)
```

But in it's contents, I cant retrieve the checkbox state or manipulate it. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: you can't do `tableClientes.getItem(x).isSelected();`?

Comment: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem does not have the property .getState();

Comment: yeah, sorry, see edit. Besides the point tho, the question is, can't you access its methods/properties like that?

Comment: tableClientes.getItem(x).getChecked(); only works when building natively the table with checkbox, not with TableEditor.

Comment: are you following [this example](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FTableEditor.html) from eclipse?

Comment: I'm following this one: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-add-swt-widgets-to-the-cells-of-the-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `setData()` method of `Widget` class. For example see the below code (specially the selection listener of last most button, but *do test for a valid widget instance*):

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class TableItemTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        shell.setLayoutData(gridData);

        final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setBounds(new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle(47,67,190,70));

        TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        tableColumn.setWidth(180);
        tableColumn.setText("Check Column"); 

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Button checkButton = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK); 
            checkButton.pack();

            TableItem tableItem=new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
            TableEditor editor = new TableEditor (table);

            editor.minimumWidth = checkButton.getSize ().x;
            editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
            editor.setEditor(checkButton, tableItem, 0);
            tableItem.setData("CHECK_BOX", checkButton); //Point to notice
        }

        Button checkState = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        checkState.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        checkState.setText("Check State");
        checkState.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    Object data = items[i].getData("CHECK_BOX");
                    if(data != null){
                        Button checkButton = (Button)data;
                        if(!checkButton.isDisposed())
                            System.out.println("For row " + (i+1) + " check status is " + checkButton.getSelection());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(220, 400);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```